# How to print json object in vector

Tags: rust

I have dummy code that reads a json file and creates a vector of the items. For debugging purposes I'd like to print this to console. However I'm faced with `cannot be formatted with the default formatter`

I have tried using `{:?}` with no luck

```
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};
use std::fs;
use std::io;
use thiserror::Error;

const DB_PATH: &str = "./data/db.json";

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Clone)]
struct Pet {
    id: usize,
    name: String,
    category: String,
    age: usize
}

#[derive(Error, Debug)]
pub enum Error {
    #[error("error reading the DB file: {0}")]
    ReadDBError(#[from] io::Error),
    #[error("error parsing the DB file: {0}")]
    ParseDBError(#[from] serde_json::Error),
}

fn read_db() -> Result<Vec<Pet>, Error> {
    let db_content = fs::read_to_string(DB_PATH)?;
    let parsed: Vec<Pet> = serde_json::from_str(&db_content)?;
    Ok(parsed)
}

fn main() {
    let pet_list = read_db().expect("can fetch pet list");
    let items: Vec<_> = pet_list;

    println!("{}",items);
}
```

What have I missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `Debug` to `#[derive(...)]` of `Pet`, Rust doesn't know how to format it. After adding you should be able to print the vector using `{:?}`.

```
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Clone, Debug)]
struct Pet {
    id: usize,
    name: String,
    category: String,
    age: usize
}
```

Also this line

```
let pet_list = read_db().expect("can fetch pet list");
```

already returns a vector, no need of the next line

```
let items: Vec<_> = pet_list;
```